# Which cloud sync software has a exclude files by type, folders by names feature?

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, cloud

I am a developer. I have a lot of Android, C# UWP, Xamarin projects on my local disc. I am using Onedrive, Dropbox, Gdrive apps currently for different use cases. However, I could not find in any of these apps a feature to exclude files by file type & folders by wildcard names, because when I build a VS Project, it creates obj and bin folders (of few GBs) that are unnecessary to be uploaded. They are just garbage after the app has finished running. So in many circumstances, many file types and folders with certain names should not be uploaded to the cloud. So far, I have tried Onedrive personal, Dropbox, Gdrive. Browsed all settings in those apps, but couldn't find such a feature. So my question is, Which cloud sync software has a exclude files by type, folders by names feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now exclude file types from being uploaded to OneDrive:
https://blog.hametbenoit.info/2020/12/15/onedrive-you-can-now-exclude-file-types-from-being-uploaded

Comment: Great help from you, guy!

Comment: It seems, it doesn't have any way to exclude folders, Am I correct?

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen you can exclude them one by one but you cannot say "exclude folders"

Comment: @MgBhadurudeen or maybe try to exclude .dir : https://superuser.com/questions/392364/what-is-the-extension-of-a-folder-in-windows#:~:text=Folder%20extensions%20are%20.,dir). but I haven't checkd that

Comment: Okay I check that. Thanks.